# Modify a drools rule to set rule attributes programmatically

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-planner, drools-flow

I see classes like `org.drools.lang.api.PackageDescrBuilder` and `org.drools.lang.api.impl.RuleDescrBuilderImpl` to create rules programmatically, but I don't see any examples of that.

Basically user will create a rule and upload the file to a location. I have read these rule files and set rule attributes like date-effective, date-expires, enabled etc.

As per `org.drools.rule.Rule` api, there are methods to set, but I don't get any idea on how to read the rule.drl file and convert it to object of type `org.drools.rule.Rule`.

Any idea on this or how to modify a drools rule using drools api will be useful.

**Note:** I don't want to do string replacement for modifying a rule.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the tests for the PackageBuilder:

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/5.6.x/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/compiler/PackageBuilderTest.java

... which has examples of doing this.